# c# handle # in url query part

Tags: c#, uri

I have one method to handle query part of urls,

```
var uri = new Uri(url);
var qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
// do some stuff
```

Here i have some special urls like below:

```
var url = "https://a.com/b?p=123&q=c# and java";
```

there is a `#` in query part and `uri.Query` only gives `p=123&q=c` and ignore the rest.

How can i deal with it in a common way?

since `#` can be used as anchor tag, so simply replace `#` with `%23` seems to be incorrect.

Comment: there also should not be any spaces in URLs

Comment: @Nick that url is just a temp string which i need to do some processing. such as turning space into `%20` or `+`

Comment: @Z'Terence: And turning `#` into `%23` of course.  Which you already note in the question, and seem to be arguing against in the answer below.  If you *already know* how to solve the problem, then what's the problem?

Comment: @David my idea was to use `regex.replace` and pass url to `new Uri(url)` .   i am worried about the situation where `#` is used as an anchor tag, like `https://a.com#b`. if that's the case, replacement is incorrect.

Comment: @David my BA told me we would not have situations like `https://a.com#b` ,so my worry is unnecessary... thanks anyway

Comment: @Z'Terence: Whatever is generating the URL should know whether it's specifying a query string value or an anchor value.  Whatever is generating the URL needs to generate *a valid URL*.  If it doesn't then nothing downstream from that error can be expected to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL is malformed.  `#` has [a specific meaning in a URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier), and nothing after it is actually sent to the server.  So C# can't do anything about that.

Wherever the URL is coming from, the query string value *should* be URL-encoded.  Something like this:

```
https://a.com/b?p=123&q=c%23%20and%20java
```

This would send the entire value to the server, where it can be URL-decoded.  (Which the framework would likely do for you, resulting in the string value you're expecting.)

Comment: the url passed to me is auto created by some logic and is just a temp string. i do some processing and wrap it to a valid url before it is sent to the server. but i cannot handle # case

Comment: @Z'Terence: Regardless of where the URL is coming from, it's invalid.  Whatever "some logic" is and whatever "some processing" is would need to result in valid URLs.  Your server-side code can't correct something that it never sees.  Whatever you're doing to create the URL needs to be corrected.